# How to show all login users data to admin using Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to show data of all users from firebase without users id in firebase `RecyclerView`. How can it be possible? I am working on my first firebase project and I am new in Firebase. Here is my code but it shows just login user data.

> java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final String uId=mUser.getUid();
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserName").child(uId);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, DashBoard.MyViewHoler>adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, MyViewHoler>(Data.class, R.layout.item_data, DashBoard.MyViewHoler.class,mDatabase) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MyViewHoler myViewHoler, Data data, int i) {
                myViewHoler.setName(data.getNamee());
                myViewHoler.setCity(data.getCityy());
                myViewHoler.setCell(data.getCelll());
                myViewHoler.setFund(data.getFundd());

            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
```

> firebase

[image: database structure image]

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: not wrong with my code i just want to see you is there any problem which not show all data without login

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("UserName").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Azar khan
khan
...
```

If you want to use Firebase-UI library to display your element in a list, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How can I retrieve data from Firebase to my adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)

Comment: This code just for login user. I mean to say that an admin can show all users data which users add in firebase.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I am making an app in which admin and users log in and after login user can add detail of fund rzr and admin can show the user name and total fund of user which donors give the user.

Comment: I cant show all these data to admin. How can i do.? I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your database to `UserName` and then `iterate` through each user to get data. Check below:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserName");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Data data = childSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);


            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: But I have initialize `mDatabase`, Probably the error from other code. Can you try directly with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserName").addListenerForSingleValueEvent...` and check

Comment: Probably it conflicts with your variable, I have change the name. Can you try with updated code and let me know?

Comment: @waqar-ahmed, Have you checked the updated answer? Is this help you?